# Find value of parameter in PDF

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $\ X $ be a random continuous variable with pdf $$\ f_x(x) = \frac{2k}{(1+kx)^3} ,\quad x > 0$$
>   What are the possible values of $\ k $ ?

My attempt:

$$\ \int f(x)dx = 1 \\ \int_0^\infty \frac{2k}{(1+kx)^3} dx = 1 \\ \frac{-1}{(1+kx)^2} \vert_0^\infty = 1$$

which doesn't get me any values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude that for *every* $k>0$ the function is a PDF.

Things go wrong if $k\leq0$.

If $k=0$ then the function is constant (actually it is the zero-function) and a constant function cannot be a PDF.

If $k<0$ then the function is not well defined for $x=-\frac1k>0$.

Unfortunately this means that no further information is found concerning the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Obvious and yet I missed it. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome.